# Future enrollment in a CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, cv, bachelor

**TL;DR**

Is it okay to list a university and an expected degree in my CV (under the education section), if the semester starts a month from now?

**Longer verion:**

I have finished bachelor studies and got accepted in a master program which starts in a month. I feel that if I leave out the master program because the semester and the classes have not actually started yet, the CV might look a bit empty.

Is it appropriate to list the imminent master studies as well?

Should I avoid having a specific starting month and simply put the year I enrolled, even if the semester is very close and it is highly unlikely that I will not attend?

Would the answer differ in industry?

If the semester was further away, more than a month, but I got the acceptance letter, is it still okay to list it?

Comment: You have not even started the masters degree yet. What do you want to say in your CV? Masters student?

Comment: Yes. One might get the impression that I am not continuing my studies if I list only a finished bachelor degree.

Comment: The master program starts in a month. What's the reason you cannot wait a month to state that you are a masters student?

Comment: Recruiting events that are happening now, and not a month from now.

Comment: Then your question may not belong to Academia.

Comment: Current events are not related to academia, true. Nevertheless, I am interested in the answers from an academic perspective, because Google came up short.

Comment: From academic perspective, you are an accepted masters student.

Comment: Exactly. How do I put that in my CV that it looks better than "accepted Master student" and do I put it at all?

Comment: I don't understand why you're going to recruiting events now.  When are you thinking you would start and end the work that might come out of the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise *against* putting anything in your CV that you have not earned experience towards. Getting accepted into an MS program is nice Kudos, but you don't have the experience yet.

Were I a prospective employer and saw the MS line and then the "expected *start*". I would immediately be soured for two reasons

1. It signals to me that the candidate does not distinguish experience from title, which further signals a reliance on status as opposed to capability.
2. It signals to me that the candidate is looking to climb without contributing.  For example, were I to hire a candidate with a CV line that said this, what's to stop them from using the just accepted position as a further selling point before they've done a day of work?

So no, just wait the month and then list your current appointment without the need for qualifiers.

Comment: Would you feel the same way if it were listed under e.g. "Plans" rather than with academic accomplishments?

Comment: A CV is for experience and accomplishments.  Plans are for the cover letter.

Comment: I have selected this as the answer because that seems to be a common theme with other "future" questions. CV for things past, cover letter for things ahead.

Answer (score 3):

Under Education, presumably you have a line for your Bachelor's.  You may also put a line for your Masters study -- perhaps something like this:

Start date: October, 2015 (tab) (name of degree, name of institution)